# JavaScript validation for username and password not working in html file

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I am creating a program called "Login & Sign-up Form". The program involve Java Servlet, HTML, CSS which are working fine and JavaScript which i am having problem. I am using JavaScript to validate the username, password and email before submitting them. However, when i click on the "Submit" button, it directly goes to page showing "log @ register success" without checking the three fields. I noticed that the email filed is only checked as it will be done by the browser automatically. Please help me to solve this issue as i do not know what is the problem. Thank you very much. Below is the html code followed by css code. I also add the java servlet code too add below. Your help is much appreciated.

****INDEX.HTML****

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8" />
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
         
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
         <title>Sign in & Sign up Form</title>
    </head>
    
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/64d58efce2.js" crossorigin="anonymous" ></script>
  
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="forms-container">
            
<!---------------------------- this is for login form ------------------------------------->
                
                <div class="login-signup">
                
                    <form action="Logsuccess" class="log-in-form" method="get">
                        <h2 class="title">Log-in</h2>
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                        </div>
                        
                        <br>
                        <span id = "user" class = "text-danger"> </span>
                        
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>
                        
                        <br>
                        <span id = "pass" class = "text-danger"> </span>
                        
                        
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn solid" />
                        <p class="social-text">Or Sign in with social platforms</p>
                        
                        <div class="social-media">
                            <a href="#" class="social-icon"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"> </i> </a>
                            <a href="#" class="social-icon"> <i class="fab fa-twitter">    </i> </a>
                            <a href="#" class="social-icon"> <i class="fab fa-google">     </i> </a>
                            <a href="#" class="social-icon"> <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i> </a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    
<!---------------------------- this is for signup form ------------------------------------->
                    
                    <!-- <form action="#" class="sign-up-form" method="post" onsubmit="return validation()">  -->
                    <form action="RegSuccess" class="sign-up-form" method="post">
                        <h2 class="title">Sign up</h2>
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                            <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" />
                        </div>
                        
                        <br>
                        <span id = "user" class = "text-danger"> </span>
                        
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                        </div>
                        
                        <br>
                        <span id = "emailAddress" class = "text-danger"> </span>
                        
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                            <input type="password" name="Password"  placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>
                        
                        <br>
                        <span id = "pass" class = "text-danger"> </span>
                                                
                        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign up" />
                        <p class="social-text">Or Sign up with social platforms</p>
                        
                        <div class="social-media">
                            <a href="#" class="social-icon"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"> </i> </a>
                            <a href="#" class="social-icon"> <i class="fab fa-twitter">    </i> </a>
                            <a href="#" class="social-icon"> <i class="fab fa-google">     </i> </a>
                            <a href="#" class="social-icon"> <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i> </a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

<!---------------------------- this is in login page for asking to signup------------------------------------->

            <div class="panels-container">
                <div class="panel left-panel">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>Don't Have An Account ?</h3>
                        <p>
                            Your are always welcome to join us!!!
                        </p>
                        
                        <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-up-btn"> Sign up </button>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/log.svg" class="image" alt="" />
                </div>

<!---------------------------- this is in signup page for asking to login------------------------------------->

                <div class="panel right-panel">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>Are You One of Us ?</h3>
                        <p>
                            Let's Log In Then !!!
                        </p>
                        
                        <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-in-btn"> Log in </button>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/register.svg" class="image" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




        <script>
            //---------------------------- this is javascript for the buttons -------------------------------------//
            const sign_in_btn = document.querySelector("#sign-in-btn");
            const sign_up_btn = document.querySelector("#sign-up-btn");
            const container = document.querySelector(".container");
            
            sign_up_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
              container.classList.add("sign-up-mode");
            });
            
            sign_in_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
              container.classList.remove("sign-up-mode");
            });
        
            //---------------------------- start of javascript for validation -------------------------------------//
        function validation()
        {
            var username = document.getElementById('username').value;  
            var password = document.getElementById('password').value;  
            
            //validation for username
            if (username == null || username == "")
            { 
                document.getElementById('user').innerHTMl = "Username cannot be empty";                 
                    return false;  
            }
            else if(username.length < 3 || username.length > 30)
            {  
                document.getElementById('user').innerHTMl = "Username must be at least 3 characters long.";  
                return false;  
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('user').innerHTMl = "";
            }
                
                
            //validation for password
            if (password == null || password == "")
            { 
                document.getElementById('pass').innerHTMl = "Password cannot be empty";                 
                return false;  
            }
            else if(password.length <= 4 || password.length >= 20)
            {  
                document.getElementById('pass').innerHTMl = "Password must be at least 4 characters long.";  
              return false;  
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('pass').innerHTMl = "";
            }
                
                
            //validation for email
            if (email == null || email == "")
            { 
                document.getElementById('emailAddress').innerHTMl = "Email cannot be empty";                    
                return false;  
            }
            else if(email.indexOf('@') <= 0)
            {  
                document.getElementById('emailAddress').innerHTMl = " @ symbol is on invalid position";  
              return false;  
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('emailAddress').innerHTMl = "";
            }
        }
        //---------------------------- end of javascript for validation -------------------------------------//
            
        </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

***LOGINFAIL.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <title>Registration Success</title>     
    </head>

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/64d58efce2.js" crossorigin="anonymous" ></script>

    <style>
        body {
          background: #041C32;
        }
        
        #card {
          position: relative;
          width: 400px;
          display: block;
          margin: 150px auto;
          text-align: center;
          font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        }
        
        #upper-side {
          padding: 2em;
          background-color: #ECB365;
          display: block;
          color: #fff;
          border-top-right-radius: 8px;
          border-top-left-radius: 8px;
        }
        
        #checkmark {
          font-weight: lighter;
          fill: #fff;
          margin: -3.5em auto auto 20px;
        }
        
        #status {
          font-weight: lighter;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          letter-spacing: 2px;
          font-size: 1em;
          margin-top: auto;
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        
        #lower-side {
          padding: 2em 2em 5em 2em;
          background: #fff;
          display: block;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
        }
        
        #message {
          margin-top: -.5em;
          color: #757575;
          letter-spacing: 1px;
        }
        
        #contBtn {
          position: relative;
          top: 1.5em;
          text-decoration: none;
          background: #064663;
          color: #fff;
          margin: auto;
          padding: .8em 3em;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.21);
          -moz-box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.21);
          box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.21);
          border-radius: 25px;
          -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
                -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
                -o-transition: all .4s ease;
                transition: all .4s ease;
        }
        
        #contBtn:hover {
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.41);
          -moz-box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.41);
          box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.41);
          -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
                -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
                -o-transition: all .4s ease;
                transition: all .4s ease;
        }
    
    </style>

    <body>      
        <section>
            <div class="rt-container">
                  <div class="col-rt-12">
                      <div class="Scriptcontent">                     
                        <div id='card' class="animated fadeIn">
                              <div id='upper-side'>
                                   <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                   <br>
                                   <h3 id='status'> Login Failed </h3> 
                                </div>
                              <div id='lower-side'>
                                <p id='message'>
                                  Your login has failed due to an invalid username or password <br><br>
                                  Please try again!!!!
                                </p>
                                <a href="index.html" id="contBtn">Continue</a>
                              </div>
                        </div>                 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

***REGISTERSUCCESS.HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <title>Registration Success</title>     
    </head>

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/64d58efce2.js" crossorigin="anonymous" ></script>

    <style>
        body {
          background: #041C32;
        }
        
        #card {
          position: relative;
          width: 400px;
          display: block;
          margin: 150px auto;
          text-align: center;
          font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        }
        
        #upper-side {
          padding: 2em;
          background-color: #ECB365;
          display: block;
          color: #fff;
          border-top-right-radius: 8px;
          border-top-left-radius: 8px;
        }
        
        #checkmark {
          font-weight: lighter;
          fill: #fff;
          margin: -3.5em auto auto 20px;
        }
        
        #status {
          font-weight: lighter;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          letter-spacing: 2px;
          font-size: 1em;
          margin-top: auto;
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        
        #lower-side {
          padding: 2em 2em 5em 2em;
          background: #fff;
          display: block;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
        }
        
        #message {
          margin-top: -.5em;
          color: #757575;
          letter-spacing: 1px;
        }
        
        #contBtn {
          position: relative;
          top: 1.5em;
          text-decoration: none;
          background: #064663;
          color: #fff;
          margin: auto;
          padding: .8em 3em;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.21);
          -moz-box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.21);
          box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.21);
          border-radius: 25px;
          -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
                -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
                -o-transition: all .4s ease;
                transition: all .4s ease;
        }
        
        #contBtn:hover {
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.41);
          -moz-box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.41);
          box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.41);
          -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
                -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
                -o-transition: all .4s ease;
                transition: all .4s ease;
        }
    
    </style>

    <body>      
        <section>
            <div class="rt-container">
                  <div class="col-rt-12">
                      <div class="Scriptcontent">                     
                        <div id='card' class="animated fadeIn">
                              <div id='upper-side'>
                                   <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                   <br>
                                   <h3 id='status'> Register Success </h3> 
                                </div>
                              <div id='lower-side'>
                                <p id='message'>
                                  Congratulations, your account has been successfully created. <br><br>
                                  Log-in to your account now !!!!
                                </p>
                                <a href="index.html" id="contBtn">Continue</a>
                              </div>
                        </div>                 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

****css code****

```
@charset "ISO-8859-1";

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #ECB365;
}

body,
input {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}


.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #041C32;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.forms-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.login-signup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 75%;
  width: 50%;
  transition: 1s 0.7s ease-in-out;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  z-index: 5;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0rem 5rem;
  transition: all 0.2s 0.7s;
  overflow: hidden;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

form.sign-up-form {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

form.log-in-form {
  z-index: 2;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  color: #ECB365;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-field {
  max-width: 380px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ECB365;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 55px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 85%;
  padding: 0 0.4rem;
  position: relative;
}

.input-field i {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
  color: #444444;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.input-field input {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #041C32;
}

.input-field input::placeholder {
  color: #444444;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.social-text {
  padding: 0.7rem 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.social-media {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social-icon {
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 0.45rem;
  color: #ECDBBA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


.social-icon:hover {
  color: #ECB365;
  border-color: #ECB365;
}

.btn {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #064663;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 49px;
  border-radius: 49px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #4d84e2;
}
.panels-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 2000px;
  top: -10%;
  right: 48%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #064663 0%, #064663 100%);
  transition: 1.8s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 6;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 1.1s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 6;
}

.left-panel {
  pointer-events: all;
  padding: 3rem 17% 2rem 12%;
}

.right-panel {
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 3rem 12% 2rem 17%;
}

.panel .content {
  color: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.9s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

.panel h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.panel p {
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  padding: 0.7rem 0;
}

.btn.transparent {
  margin: 0;
  background: #041C32;
  /*border: 2px solid #fff;*/
  width: 130px;
  height: 41px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.btn.transparent:hover {
  background-color: #4d84e2;
}

.right-panel .image,
.right-panel .content {
  transform: translateX(800px);
}

/* ANIMATION */

.container.sign-up-mode:before {
  transform: translate(100%, -50%);
  right: 52%;
}

.container.sign-up-mode .left-panel .image,
.container.sign-up-mode .left-panel .content {
  transform: translateX(-800px);
}

.container.sign-up-mode .login-signup {
  left: 25%;
}

.container.sign-up-mode form.sign-up-form {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container.sign-up-mode form.log-in-form {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container.sign-up-mode .right-panel .image,
.container.sign-up-mode .right-panel .content {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.container.sign-up-mode .left-panel {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container.sign-up-mode .right-panel {
  pointer-events: all;
}

@media (max-width: 870px) {
  .container {
    min-height: 800px;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .login-signup {
    width: 100%;
    top: 95%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    transition: 1s 0.8s ease-in-out;
  }

  .login-signup,
  .container.sign-up-mode .login-signup {
    left: 50%;
  }

  .panels-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  }

  .panel {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2.5rem 8%;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
  }

  .right-panel {
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
  }

  .left-panel {
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
  }

  .image {
    width: 200px;
    transition: transform 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.6s;
  }

  .panel .content {
    padding-right: 15%;
    transition: transform 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.8s;
  }

  .panel h3 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  .panel p {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
  }

  .btn.transparent {
    width: 110px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
  }

  .container:before {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 1500px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 30%;
    bottom: 68%;
    right: initial;
    top: initial;
    transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  }

  .container.sign-up-mode:before {
    transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
    bottom: 32%;
    right: initial;
  }

  .container.sign-up-mode .left-panel .image,
  .container.sign-up-mode .left-panel .content {
    transform: translateY(-300px);
  }

  .container.sign-up-mode .right-panel .image,
  .container.sign-up-mode .right-panel .content {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }

  .right-panel .image,
  .right-panel .content {
    transform: translateY(300px);
  }

  .container.sign-up-mode .login-signup {
    top: 5%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 570px) {
  form {
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
  }

  .image {
    display: none;
  }
  .panel .content {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  }
  .container {
    padding: 1.5rem;
  }

  .container:before {
    bottom: 72%;
    left: 50%;
  }

  .container.sign-up-mode:before {
    bottom: 28%;
    left: 50%;
  }
}
```

***RegSucess.java***

```
package com.assignmentwpj;

import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletConfig;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;



public class RegSuccess extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public RegSuccess() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at : ").append(request.getContextPath());
    
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
          String Username = request.getParameter("Username");
            String Password = request.getParameter("Password");
        
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            
            context.setAttribute("Username", Username);
            context.setAttribute("Password", Password);
        
             
            
            
             RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("registersuccess.html");
            req.forward(request, response);
            
        
    }
        
}
```

***LogSucess.java***

```
package com.assignmentwpj;


import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;





public class Logsuccess extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Logsuccess() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        
        String UserName =(String)context.getAttribute("Username");
        String PassWord =(String)context.getAttribute("Password");
        
        if(username.equals(UserName) && password.equals(PassWord))
        {
    
            RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("loginsuccess.html");
            req.forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
            RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("LoginFail.html");
            req.forward(request, response);
        }
        
        
        
}
    
}
```

Comment: Your `validation` method does not appear to be called by anything in the browser.

Comment: is it? how shall i make it called? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Jon P's answer adding "required" in your html  like:

```
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
```

will make it a required field for submission, this wont fix the validation problem but right now you would not need to give any response to continue

Answer (score 0):

As Jon P mentioned, your validation function (in INDEX.HTML) exists without being actually called for action.

My understanding of what you're trying to do is to validate three input fields for the sign up (username, email, password) when clicking on "Sign up" button. If this is true, then we want to add event listener to this button and call your validation function.

```
<!-- Add event listener to this input button. -->
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign up" />
```

```
const sign_up_submit_btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

sign_up_submit_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if ( validation ) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Show an error message
    }
})
```

The validation function also need to return true in the else {} statement :

```
        function validation()
        {
            var username = document.getElementById('username').value;  
            var password = document.getElementById('password').value;  
            
            //validation for username
            if (username == null || username == "")
            { 
                document.getElementById('user').innerHTMl = "Username cannot be empty";                 
                    return false;  
            }
            else if(username.length < 3 || username.length > 30)
            {  
                document.getElementById('user').innerHTMl = "Username must be at least 3 characters long.";  
                return false;  
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('user').innerHTMl = "";
                return true;
            }
                
                
            //validation for password
            if (password == null || password == "")
            { 
                document.getElementById('pass').innerHTMl = "Password cannot be empty";                 
                return false;  
            }
            else if(password.length <= 4 || password.length >= 20)
            {  
                document.getElementById('pass').innerHTMl = "Password must be at least 4 characters long.";  
              return false;  
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('pass').innerHTMl = "";
                return true;
            }
                
                
            //validation for email
            if (email == null || email == "")
            { 
                document.getElementById('emailAddress').innerHTMl = "Email cannot be empty";                    
                return false;  
            }
            else if(email.indexOf('@') <= 0)
            {  
                document.getElementById('emailAddress').innerHTMl = " @ symbol is on invalid position";  
              return false;  
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('emailAddress').innerHTMl = "";
                return true;
            }
        }
```